# Check a radio button with data from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I have the  following radio buttons :

```
<td valign="top">
    <label>Have you ever been tested?</label>

    <input required id="Test" name="Test" type="radio" class="wellness_center radiostyle" value="1">
    <div class="radiolabel">Yes</div>
    <input required id="Test" name="Test" type="radio" class="wellness_center radiostyle" value="0">
    <div class="radiolabel">No</div>
</td>
```

Which submits data to the  database in the  form of 0 and 1 (1=Yes,0=No). 
I would like to pull this information from the database and re-map/highlight back the radio button based on the value that was saved in the database. I tried the  following method :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "database/Emarps/websrvc/websrvc.php?task=getData&UUID=" + currentuuid + "&DataGt=hk",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (response) {
        $.each(response, function (i, resp) {

            if (resp.tested === $("input[name='Test'][value='1']").prop('checked', true)) {

            } else if (resp.tested === $("input[name='Test'][value='0']").prop('checked', true)) {

            }

        });
    }
});
```

Which retrieves the  data very well from the  database but it fails to map it to the respective radio buttons. Please assist , how can I map it back to the right radio base on values from Database passed through JSON?

Comment: Don't use same `id` in radio buttons.

Comment: resp.tested  what is coming in this response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare, you may simply use literal:

```
if (resp.tested === "1") {
  $("input[name='Test'][value='1']").prop('checked', true);
}
```

You may try this instead:

```
$("input[name=Test]").prop('checked', false); //uncheck all
$.each(response, function (i, resp) {
  $("input[name=Test][value=" + resp.tested + "]").prop('checked', true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just check the radio, whose value is saved in the database

```
//assuming response is an array
$.each(response, function (i, resp) {
    $("input[name='Test'][value='" + resp.tested + "']").prop('checked', true))
});
```